# How to tell if a file has already been required?

Tags: php, require

I've created a php global file (globs.php), and have required it in all of my pages. 
However, some pages are now including other pages, and I'm getting an error when it tries to require globs.php again.

How can I tell if a file has been required? That way, I could do if !required('globs.php') require('globs.php').

Comment: Do you have control over the require statements? If so, you can use require_once() instead.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can also make your own require_file function:

> ```
> <?php
> function require_file($file_path){
>     static $required_files=array();
>     if(!isset($required_files[$file_path])){
>         require $file_path;
>         $required_files[$file_path]=true;
>         return true;
>     }
>     return false;
> }
> ?>
> ```

Comment: This function is already implemented in PHP for you: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php see my answer.

Comment: This only works if you use it to include literally everything. As soon as you add in composer or PSR-4 or anything else that manages file inclusion to the mix, this immediately becomes completely unreliable. Just use the built in.

Answer (score 33):

Use [require_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) instead:

> The _require_once_ statement is identical to [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) except PHP will check if the file has already been included, and if so, not include (require) it again...

Answer (score 23):

## [*array* `get_included_files` ( *void* )](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php)

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php

Gets the names of all files that have been included using [include](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), [include_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php), [require](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) or [require_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)

### Return values

> Returns an array of the names of all files.
>
> The script originally called is considered an "included file," so it will be listed
>   together with the files referenced by include and family.
>
> Files that are included or required multiple times only show up once in the returned array.

---

### `get_included_files()` example

```
<?php
// This file is abc.php

include 'test1.php';
include_once 'test2.php';
require 'test3.php';
require_once 'test4.php';

$included_files = get_included_files();

foreach ($included_files as $filename) {
    echo "$filename\n";
}

?>
```

The above example will output:

```
abc.php
test1.php
test2.php
test3.php
test4.php
```

---

Comment: This should be considered the answer to the question. If this includes a custom function to implement a single callback would make it more simple. For example, function check_include($file) { $include_files = get_included_files(); return in_array($file, $include_files); }

Answer (score 4):

Best solution is require_once(), which uses the same syntax as require() but performs the checking you're talking about automatically.

If you really need to know if it's been required already, I suggest defining a constant in your included file and checking it's value.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there is a function defined in the file you're looking to include, you can also do a quick

```
 if (!function_exists('foo')) {
     require('bar.php');
 }
```

Use what best suits your setup.

Comment: I used WisdomPanda's approach on a class, my example uses JSMIN `if(!method_exists('JSMIN', 'minify')) { require_once('libs/JSMin.php'); }`